# Debugging is not working

Tags: android, android-studio

From today morning doesn't know what is happening in my android studio[image: I am getting the window like this]
I reinstalled the android studio but still, it doesn't change I have no idea what is the issue
I tried to install the Android support but seems it is not available.
[image]

Comment: I can see two clear error messages that point to obvious resolvable problems.  Have you tried resolving them?

Comment: Ya I tried almost every thing it was working perfectly tomorrow and now it is showing this I saw some post and it said to reinstall and then I posted this question

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio go to

> File -> Settings - > Plugins -> Enable "Android Support" Plugin.

[image]